# I am trying to convert curl request to c# request but it is not working

Tags: c#, curl, request

I am trying to convert a curl request to c# request but it is not working

curl request

```
curl -X GET "http://www1.bloomingdales.com/shop/search?keyword=lace%2Btop"
```

The above curl request works fine

C# request

```
public lib_check ()
    {

        string url_1 = "http://www1.bloomingdales.com/shop/search/Pageindex%2CProductsperpage/1%2C180?keyword=women%20tank%20top";
        Console.Write (url+"request started");

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_1);

        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;

        var response = request.GetResponse();
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {

            var json = reader.ReadToEnd ();

            console.write( json);

        }
    }
```

But the above c# request throws 403 forbidden error

How to fix c# request and make request working to get 200 response?

Comment: Could you try curl'ing the same URL as in the C# code and seeing if you can get a response?

Comment: no i could not i get 403 error

Comment: 403 forbidden usually means it is not available unless you are authenticated. If you can curl the URL but get no response in C#, then its cause for concern (e.g. something wrong/missing in code). For your case, the only problem is with authentication, not code-related.

Comment: but it works with restsharp

Comment: var client = new RestClient("http://www1.bloomingdales.com/shop/search/Pageindex,Productsperpage/1,180?keyword=women%2520tank%2520top");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Comment: but it want to make it working with  this var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_1); default library

Comment: I tried the same link on Advanced Rest Client (GET, no authentication headers) and got a 403 forbidden. Are you certain RestSharp is giving you correct results and you haven't added an api key or any extra headers?

Comment: yes it gave me correct results without any additional headers

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason why it's forbidden because you didn't construct the necessary header that the site is expecting. You need to construct those headers and you can check it in developer tools in chrome. See code below.

```
string url_1 = @"http://www1.bloomingdales.com/shop/search/Pageindex%2CProductsperpage/1%2C180?keyword=women%20tank%20top";

var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_1);

request.Method = "GET";   
request.Accept = "text/html";            
request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework Test Client"; // Some server prevent script like this so they validate some user-agents
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = int.MaxValue;
request.Timeout = 50000;

var response = request.GetResponse();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{

    var json = reader.ReadToEnd();

    Console.Write(json);

}
```

To see what are the headers needed by the server; try requesting the url in browser first while dev tools are active.

[image]

**Update :** If this doesn't work well due to timeout issue it better to handle it asynchronously.

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    AllowAutoRedirect = true,
    CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
    UseCookies = true,
    AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate
};

var client = new HttpClient(handler)
{
    Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 3, 0)
};

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/html"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.ExpectContinue = false;
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US, en");

var result = client.GetAsync("http://www1.bloomingdales.com/shop/search/Pageindex%2CProductsperpage/1%2C180?keyword=women%20tank%20top").Result;

var content = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

Console.Write(content);
```

*I noticed the result is not json but a page. May be because it's not API.* Adjust the code as needed but the bare bone was already there.

Comment: This method works for you and did u got response back as 200?

Comment: what's the exception?

Comment: same 403 forbidden

Comment: Try my new update in the answer. It may take a while because of many redirects so increase the timeout :)

Comment: 50000 is number of secs?